# What happens if I buy an exotic pet in Ohio and take it to my home in Pennsylvania?

Tags: legal, exotic-pets, fox

I have heard that Ohio has different laws (or maybe no laws) governing the making of pets of wild, exotic and/or non-native species.  I have also heard that occasionally people will purchase a "pet" in Ohio and bring it home to Pennsylvania.  Some time later, the Pennsylvanian authorities are involved.

Example:

Someone has purchased a [Silver Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_fox_%28animal%29) in Ohio and brought to their home in Pennsylvania, they look out in the drive way and see official looking vehicles pulling in.

So what happens now?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you know that this is against the laws of Ohio or Pennsylvania or both. If it is, I would expect the animal to be confiscated and you may be charged with a criminal offense. If you are unsure of the laws, you should investigate them before hand.

I would also urge you to consider the welfare of the animal. How likely is this wild animal to become domesticated? What kind of life will you offer it? Being cooped up in an outside pen or confined to a cage within a house sounds like a miserable existence to me.

Comment: +1 this is a good answer, check a couple of comments I left in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10964?m=17601551#17601551) that may help you improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when the authorities pull up?

There is no definitive answer as each state has its own laws and methods.  Many states require permits for different classifications of exotic pets, and those rules may change on a periodic basis.  It really depends on the pet and the laws regarding that pet.  Some animals get locked up, some get euthanized, some get deported to rehabilitation centers / farms / adoption agencies in other states where keeping the animal is legal.  Depending on the severity of the offense and possibly the situation, the owner can have any penalty, from none to being fined, to being incarcerated.